Bulk emails sent from a secondary Outlook account show up in my primary sent items box
I had my company set up a group mailbox for saving sent emails.
It works when I send one email manually.
The problem comes when I try to use an Excel tool I built to send mail en masse. The emails look like they're from the group box, but they show up in my sent items.
Streamlined code below.
The email 'From' box says

GroupBox@email.com.

When you hover, it says

From GroupBox@email.com; Send using account: turts@email.com

Sub BulkEmail()

    Dim objoutlook As Object
    Dim objmail As Object
    Dim objAttmt As String
    Dim i, n As Integer

    n = 2
    
    For i = 1 To n
        Set objoutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
        Set objmail = objoutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objmail
            .sentonbehalfofname = "GroupBox@email.com"
            .To = "recipient@email.com"
            .Subject = "Payment due from account #" & i
            .body = "Please remit payment for account number " & i & "."
            .Display 'or .send
        End With
        Set objoutlook = Nothing
        Set objmail = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub

I tried using sendusingaccount instead of sentonbehalfofname.
It shows as coming from my primary account.
I tried using Sessions.Accounts from other posts here (e.g. MS Access / Outlook 2010 - how to choose which account to send email from?).
It works the same as above (depending on whether sentonbehalfofname or sendusingaccount is used, it either shows as from my primary email or "from the groupbox; send using account: primary").
Is there some other send function aside from sentonbehalfofname or sendusingaccount.
I want sent mail to show up in the Group box sent items.

See Switching the FROM Inbox. Run Sub ShowAllAccounts() to verify "GroupBox@email.com" is set up as an account recognized by VBA. You can then try Set .SendUsingAccount =. (Without Set this is unreliable.)
